# How many elements does the factor ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2-2)$ have? Find the multiplicative inverses of $x, x+1$ and $3x+2$ in this ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

How many elements does the factor ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2-2)$ have? Find the multiplicative inverses of $x, x+1$ and $3x+2$ in this ring.

Total novice here - how would you be able to count the number of elements in the factor ring? And in this case, if someone could find one multiplicative inverse, e.g $3x+2$, I'm sure can solve the rest. Many thanks.

Comment: This goes the same ways as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148371/how-many-elements-there-exist-in-polynomial-quotient-ring-mathbbz-5x-x2).

Comment: Thank you! Could you help with the multiplicative inverse part?

Comment: The multiplicative inverse goes the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068641/multiplicative-inverse-of-2x-3-i-in-mathbbz-5x-i).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(x^2-2)$ means that you look at the ring $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$ with the relation $x^2-2=0$, or equivalently, $x^2=2$. This means that whenever you have a polynomial of degree $\geq 2$ you can reduce it to a linear polynomial (since you can replace every $x^2$ with $2$). For example, $$\begin{align}3x^4+2x^3+x^2+1=\\3(x^2)^2+2x(x^2)+(x^2)+1=\\3(2)^2+2x(2)^2+(2)+1=\\8x+15=\\3x\end{align}$$

working modulo $5$. This means that every element in $\mathbb{Z}_5 [x]/(x^2-2)$ is on the form $a+bx$, where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_5$. Now, how many possibilities are there for $a,b$? This will give you the number of elements in $\mathbb{Z}_5 [x]/(x^2-2)$.

Now for inverses. 
$$(x+1)(a+bx)=(a+b)x+a+2b=1$$

So $a+2b\equiv_5 1$ and $a+b\equiv_5 0$, using that $x^2=2$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: I get your explanation for the number of elements. They would be 25. That was really helpful. For the inverses, however, I'm still not sure where you were trying to go with that.

Comment: All the elements are on the form $a+bx$, which means that the inverse of $x+1$ (if it exists) also would be on that form. Since we want $a+bx$ to be the inverse of $x+1$, we want $(x+1)(a+bx)=1$, expanding and comparing coefficients we get that $a+b\equiv_5 0$, which means $a\equiv_5 4b$ and also we have $a+2b\equiv_5 1$. This gives $4b+2b\equiv_5 6b\equiv_5 b\equiv_5 1$. Therefore $a\equiv_5 -1$ and $b\equiv_5 1$, and the inverse is $-1+x$. Is this helpful?